# How to git remove a file completely even from commit history?

Tags: git, large-files

I committed a remove of a large file. Now I want this large file out of my local `.git`. Any steps to follow which would work?

I tried:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch$files" HEAD
```

and this

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $file'  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: The command `git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $Rakefile' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all` works for me. Being at repo-root directory and $Rakefile including the relative path of that to-be-removed file . `linux , git version 2.6.4`.

Answer (score 0):

The magic git command you're looking for is [git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), which lets you edit your git repo.  The first example in the *EXAMPLES* section is:

```
   Suppose you want to remove a file (containing confidential information
   or copyright violation) from all commits:

       git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm filename' HEAD
```

Comment: Cannot create a new backup.
A previous backup already exists in refs/original/
Force overwriting the backup with -f

Comment: Add '-f' as that parameter is forcing to do the stuff, so: `git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm filename' HEAD`